# How can I create an environment with the same indentation of the itemize environment?

Tags: numbering, lists, environments, enumerate, itemize

I'd like to create an environment or a command that indents the text and enumerate the first line. Here's a graphic of what I want:

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[23pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{quest}
\newenvironment{example}
{\refstepcounter{quest}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item[\thequest.]\textbf{}\hspace{10pt}}
    {\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

But that doesn't work, and I can't find out how to avoid the problem it gives. Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see, its not as the first image. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could use the `enumitem` package for this.

Comment: I can't, I have to use it as an alone command, the way I've explained.

Comment: I need an ongoing list, but with the possibility of putting things offlist over the whole document, anytime I want.

Comment: It's possible resume the numbering if you put something between by passing `[resume*]` to the following list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional packages.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{quest}
\newenvironment{example}
{\refstepcounter{quest}
  \par
  \leftskip 40pt\relax% PARAGRAPH INDENT
  \noindent
  \llap{\makebox[15pt][l]{\thequest.}}% DEFINES LEFT OFFSET OF LABEL
  \ignorespaces
}
{  \par\leftskip 0pt\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or use `\llap{\thequest.\hspace{\labelsep}}` for right aligned numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a list with the `enumitem` package and set the widths with the keys `leftmargen`, `labelsep`, and `labelwidth` (see [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)). To resume the numbering add `[resume*]` to the following lists.

```
\documentclass[23pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myitemize}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myitemize]{
    label*=\arabic*.,
    leftmargin = 3em,
    labelsep = 1em,
    labelwidth = 2em
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{myitemize}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{myitemize}[resume*]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]